# git message "load pubkey ... invalid format" after upgrade to Git 2.27

Tags: git, ssh-keys

After upgrading to **Git 2.27** (on Windows) whenever I execute operations on remote repositories authorized with SSH, Git emits *"load pubkey ... invalid format"* claiming that the private key file has an invalid format. The operation is executed successfully anyway but message is strange.

Checked file format (UTF) and LF line endings, copied private key file from an unmodified source to `.ssh` folder. No success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this issue: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2743 and copied corresponding `.pub` file to `.ssh` folder: works again